# How to predict from model without training again?

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, machine-learning, flask

I'm deploying a Flask app on heroku for prediciting from an ML Model. How do I make predictions without training again for each prediction?

It works well on Jupyter Notebook as I have to just change the input values and execute that particular cell for prediction. But when the entire code is being run on Heroku or even VSC, it trains again and again.

```py
file = ("file.csv")
names = ['index1','index2','index3','output']
.
.
X_train,X_validation,Y_train,Y_validation=model_selection.train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=validation_size,random_state=seed)
.
.
models.append(('KNN',KNeighborsClassifier()))
..
results=[]
names=[]
for name,model in models:
    kfold=model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10,random_state=seed)
    cv_results=model_selection.cross_val_score(model,X_train,Y_train,cv=kfold)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)

knn=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
knn.fit(X_train,Y_train)
predictions=knn.predict(X_validation)


//I need to make predicitions for the input below:
knn.predict(np.asmatrix([152,92,1,60,70]))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you execute `.fit` then it will obviously train again and it seems you do exactely that. If you want to deploy an already trained classifier you have to save it, so it does not loose its trained weights.

If you want to persist the your trained classifier sklearn suggests three options:

- [pickle](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html): Just pickle the trained classifier and restore it.
- [onnxmltools](https://github.com/onnx/onnxmltools): ONNX is a common exchange tool for already trained classifiers that you can load for prediction.
- [sklearn2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml): Same story as with ONNX just a different format PMML.

I honestly don't know which is the best option and I did not test them, but you should do loading performance tests, since it is a heroku app, or even consider a persistent global variable with your classifier(don't forget locking!).